# Consuming a webservice php with C#

Tags: c#, php, serialization, soap, web-reference

here is the wsdl soap field

```
<element name="transactionCle" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
```

when I call the WS in PHP and I show the soap with `__getLastResponse()`

I get that for the transactionCle :

```
<transactionCle href="#id50"/>
```

here is the ref of the field :

```
<multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id50" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:int">12708584</multiRef>
```

I added a new WebReference to a wsdl provided by an Apache Server working with php.
The proxy class generated give me for the field :

```
private System.Nullable<int> transactionCleField;

/// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<int> transactionCle {
            get {
                return this.transactionCleField;
            }
            set {
                this.transactionCleField = value;
            }
        }
```

Now my Problem :

**When I consume the WS in php the value of transactionCle is 12708584

when I consume the WS in C# the value of transactionCle is null**

If I modify manualy the proxy class from System.Nullable to int
And now C# give me the Good Value (12708584).

**but when I update the Webreference I have to modify again the proxy classes.**

Here is my question :
How can I :
or set transactionCle to int type without modify the proxy class?
or make the serialisation give me the Good Value?

**edit : I'm not able to modify the WS php or the wsdl**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attributes to the transactionCle-element in the wsdl

```
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
```

Then regenerate the proxy. If it helps, then you can do three things:

1. change the generated proxy by hand (which you already mentioned you won't)
2. ask the WS-owner to extend the generated wsdl. This will ensure .net compatibility of the webservice
3. create your own proxy generator by overriding methods of the SchemaImporterExtension. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.advanced.schemaimporterextension.aspx . It also has a link to a downloadable sample.

Comment: sorry I edited My question I cannot modify the WS my modification must be C# side

Comment: I wondered if you had a chance to test the modified wsdl with the minOccurs and maxOccurs.

Comment: unfortunately the webservice I'm calling is in production and is from another company so I cannot modify it

Comment: I was hopping a best solution, but I wonder there is not. Thank you, I will wait a little bit for the bounty maybe someone else will give me another clue. but +1 Thanks